# Find a pmf of random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a Random Variable with pdf $f_x(x)=1/2$ for $-1<x<1$.

$Y=I_{[X>0.75]}=\begin{cases}
    1       & \quad \text{if } x>0.75\\
    0  & \quad \text{if } x \leq 0.75\\
  \end{cases}$

Find the pmf of the random variable Y

Comment: $Y$ is discrete, so it has no pdf, it has a pmf.

Comment: And obviously $\mathsf P(Y{=}1) = \mathsf P(\boxed{\,?\,}), \mathsf P(Y{=}0) = \mathsf P(\boxed{\,?\,})$

Comment: I have sloved it, thank you for your hints.